# What is the contrary - not the contradictory - of $(A\rightarrow B)$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In traditional logic, there was a distinction between " contradictory" sentences and " contrary" sentences. The relation holding between contrary sentences meant maximal opposition.

For example, the contradictory of "all $A$ is $B$" is simply  "not all $A$ is $B$", but the contrary is " all $A$ is not-$B$" ( or no $A$ is $B$).

I'm wondering whether this distinction also applies to modern propositional logic.

Can one say that the contrary of $(A \to B)$ is $(A \to \lnot B)$?

Normally contrary sentences can be false at the same time ( but not true at the same time).

Comment: $A\implies B$ and $A\implies \neg B$ are not contrary, since they can simultaneously be true. For example, when $A$ is false, then both implications are true.

Comment: I had not noticed that, you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two statements in propositional logic are contrary when they cannot both be true at the same time.

Thus, as pointed our in the comments, $A \to B$ and $A \to \neg B$ are certainly not contrary, since they can both be true, simply by setting $A$ to False.

OK, but you can certainly always find *some* contrary statement to an propositional logic statement by negating it ... this would also be its contradictory statement.

But any statement can have many non-equivalent contrary statements, e.g. both $A \land \neg B$ as well as $A \land \neg A$ are contrary to $A \to B$, but these are not equivalent to each other. Indeed, while $A \land \neg B$ and $A \to B$ are contradictory, $A \land \neg A$ and $A \to B$ are not.

Ok, but out of all contrary statements, is there some 'maximally' contrary statement? Frankly I have not heard of any such thing in the context of propositional logic ... intuitively one could maybe point to a contradiction like $A \land \neg A$ as such a statement that 'maximally goes against' any statement ... but at the same time that is not at all very interesting or useful. So, I think such a notion simply does not exist in propositional logic.

Comment: Found a link that confirms the idea that a proposition can have many contraries. The example given is ( with G for " God exists" and S for " Satan exists") :  (~G & S) and (~G&~S)  are both contrary to G. Unfortunately, the document does not treat the case of implication.    [ author Jean-Yves Béziau  ; link : www.jyb-logic.org/sep.pdf ]

Answer (score 0):

Note, that in classical logic, $\phi\rightarrow\psi$ fails exactly when $\phi$ is true and $\psi$ is false. Formally, it thus holds that $\phi\rightarrow\psi\equiv\neg\phi\lor\psi$.

Thus, the formal negation of $\phi\rightarrow\psi$ is given by

$$\neg(\phi\rightarrow\psi)\equiv\neg(\neg\phi\lor\psi)\equiv\phi\land\neg\psi$$